# Entering Ctrl+Z for ending reading words will cause a loop error

Tags: c++

Here is my code, If you enter "Ctrl+Z" it should finish, but it will go into loop mode and it repeats writing the last word.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  char word[80];
   do
   {  cin >> word;
      if (*word) cout << "\t\"" << word << "\"\n";
   }  while (*word);
}
```

By Pressing "Ctrl+Z" this simple program should end, but why it is not going in this way? what is problem with it?

Look at this code:

```
{  char line[80];
   do
   {  cin.getline(line,80);
      if (*line) cout << "\t[" << line << "]\n";
   } while (*line);
}
```

it is similar to the first code, but this time it is working fine and it will exit loop by pressing "Ctrl+Z"

So what is the exact problem with first code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exit the loop because `*word` is not null-character; `word` still points to the  buffer read in the previous iteration, and it does gets erased when you press Ctrl+Z.

You should write the loop as:

```
while(cin >> word) { /* your code */ }
```

then it should exit the loop once you press Ctrl+Z

Also, it is better to declare `word` as `std::string` instead of `char[80]`:

```
std::string word; //#include <string>

while (cin >> word)
{  
  cout << "\t\"" << word << "\"\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but why my code is not working really? look at the second code I have added to first Post. it is working fine and by pressing crtl+z it will exit loop. so waht is the exact problem with first code?

Comment: @Stranger: Because `getline` writes an empty string to its argument even if couldn't read anything, while (as the answer says) `>>` only modifies its operand if it successfully read and converted something; it *won't* overwrite `word` with an empty string if you close the stream.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for your reply,@Nawaz your code is good too, but it has a problem, first of all I'm not allowed to use strings, second your code will write the last word after pressing ctrl+z, but I need after pressing enter after each word, the program write it and ctrl+z only exit the loop and the program. so what should I do?